# Why does Oracle View shows different output when use select * from view

Tags: view, oracle11g

I have a View in Oracle. It's called:
invoices

When I call the View directly it shows me my data like this:
select * from invoices

```
>     +-------+------------+------------+
>     | Name  | InvoiceNo  |   Street   |
>     +-------+------------+------------+
>     | 1111  |      Peter | Pencilroad |
>     | 2222  |      Clint | Duffstreet |
>     +-------+------------+------------+
```

When I use the select statement from the view it shows me a different output:
select epname as name, epno as invoiceno, epst as street from ep

```
>     +-------+-----------+------------+
>     | Name  | InvoiceNo |   Street   |
>     +-------+-----------+------------+
>     | Peter |      1111 | Pencilroad |
>     | Clint |      2222 | Duffstreet |
>     +-------+-----------+------------+
```

How is this possible?
I compiled the view again and it shows me still the different data. I also checked if the View is Invalid, but it isn't.

Any clues? I am using SQLDeveloper on an Oracle 11g database.
Is there also a way, to see the changes made to the view in the past or changelog with username and timestamp?

Thanks in advance.

Content from All_objects:

```
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| OWNER |   OBJECT_NAME   | SUBOBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_ID | DATA_OBJECT_ID | OBJECT_TYPE |       CREATED       | LAST_DDL_TIME | TIMESTAMP | STATUS | TEMPORARY | GENERATED | SECONDARY | NAMESPACE | EDITION_NAME |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| AUW   | INVOICES        |         30367  | VIEW      | 16.01.15       | 07.10.15    | 2015-10-05:13:44:13 | VALID         | N         | N      | N         |         1 |           |           |              |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Create View statement:

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICES AS
SELECT TRIM (person.NAME || NVL2 (person.Surname, ',' || person.Surname, '')) AS Name,
          RTRIM (egy.e90sart1 || egy.E90SART2) AS InvoiceNo,
          TRIM (person.street) AS Street
   FROM   person,
          egy
   WHERE      person.key = egy.key;
```

Comment: so only column order differs?

Comment: The order of the columns is the same, but the content is changed. It saves me with the statement: select * from invoices the invoiceno in name. I copied the view to a new one and it strangely it shows me the correct data in the new one...

Comment: This could be something like: `create view abc(c1, c2, c3) as select c2, c1, c3 from .... `

Comment: Show us the `create view` statement

Comment: Not really, because the statement the view is using shows the output correct: select epname as name, epno as invoiceno, epst as street from ep.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution how to solve this problem:
I renamed the view and suddenly it worked. I'm still wondering why compiling did not work, however now it is fine.